# I can not send mail in drupal-7

Tags: drupal-7

I began to learn about drupal, I perform the function send mail but failed. Please could help me:

```
 $params = array(
'subject' => 'hello',
'body' => 'test',);
$from='nguyen.xuan.luan@vinicorp.com.vn'; 
$to = 'nguyen.xuan.luan@vinicorp.com.vn';
$mail = drupal_mail('exampe', 'notice', $to, language_default(), $params,  $from, TRUE);
```

error message: **Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.**

I think that must have information of mail password but I do not know how. Please can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one hook i.e. hook_mail in your .module file and set message subject and body there. Below is the working hook_mail() implementation for your code -

```
function exampe_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    switch($key) {
        //switching on $key lets you create variations of the email based on the $key parameter
        case 'notice':
            $message['subject'] = t('Subject');
            //the email body is here, inside the $message array
            $message['body'][] = 'This is the body of the email';
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek Srivastava. I tried using smtp but the results are so